# easiest way to geometrically perform circle inversion

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I would like to know which of the available methods of performing circle inversion of a point is the fastest or simplest. 
Obs.: Simplicity here may be taken to be inversely proportional to the number of steps in the construction with straightedge and compass.

Best wishes,

Comment: There is an apposite macro in Geogebra and a mechanical device, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaucellier%E2%80%93Lipkin_linkage

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be your circle, whose center will be represented by $O$. Let $P$ be the point whose inversion you want to determine. Let $r$ be the ray with origin at $O$ passing through $P$.

### If $P$ is inside the circle:

1. draw the line $l$ orthogonal to $r$ passing through $P$;
2. let $T$ be one of the points of $l\cap c$;
3. draw the line $l^\star$ passing through $T$ orthogonal to the line segment $OT$;
4. then the inversion of $P$ is the point $P'$ at which the line $l^\star$ intersects $r$.

### If $P$ is outside the circle:

1. draw the circle $c'$ centered at the midpoint of $OP$ passing through $P$;
2. let $T$ be one of the points of $c\cap c'$;
3. draw the line $l$ defined by $P$ and $T$;
4. draw the line $l^\star$ orthogonal to $r$ passing through $T$;
5. then the inversion of $P$ is the point $P'$ at which the line $l^\star$ intersects $r$.

Comment: One could simply connect the two points of $c\cap c'$ with a line...

Comment: @ccorn Sure! I missed that.